# What event to use instead of onmouseout to run when mouse is not over the element?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

i want to run a script when i'm not hovering an element. It's some kind of deactivating something else that was run previously in 'onmouseover' event.
So I'm using onmouseout event to run this script, however , **the problem is** that if i don't hover the element and then leave it , the script just don't run.
this happens if e.g  hover the element too fast or the window loses focus .
How can i solve that?

**EDIT:**  let me illustrate this in another way , what i need is an event to be run when an element isn't touched by mouse.

Comment: not detecting hover if the mouse moves too fast isn't possible unless you track the mouse movement manually and trigger all your hovers yourself. Then you can add linear interpolation to check the mouse cursor movement between frames and compute all onMouseX events.

Comment: well , maybe i don't want to detect hover here, i want to check whether mouse is over or not

Comment: if `onMouseOut` is lost due to fast movement, then so is `onMouseOver`, so you can track your state properly.

Comment: You probably want to run the same script that runs on `onMouseOut` on script load as well.

Comment: right, but what happens here is that i enter the elements  normally but leave them very fast ..

Comment: what do you mean, please illustrate?

Comment: Then their `onMouseOut` event shall trigger, albeit possibly in incorrect order (new elements are entered before old elements are left)

Comment: "(new elements are entered before old elements are left)"
this is exactly what happens !

Comment: `onMouseOut` shall trigger when the mouse cursor leaves the element (i.e. was inside and isn't).

Comment: I don't think the event order will be reversed (over before out) contrary to expectations but you can't expect much from IE8

Answer (score 2):

you can try this,

```
<div id="div1" onmouseover="fucntionIn()" onmouseout="functionOut()">"Special Area"</div>
<div id="div2" onmouseover="fucntionOut()">Other area</div>
```

the logic is to write deactivate code for onmouseover event of other area of the page.

Comment: i like your logic, however, the deactivation code must run for that element that had run the activation code .

Comment: hmmm.... then you have to set an attribute when you deactivate an element. then select the element using document.getElementById(). and check whether it is activated using the attribute. if it is activated, deactivate it.

Comment: "check whether it is activated" 
in what event?

Comment: You can use Jquery to do this type of things very easily. Check this out. http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: I have written the sample code here (http://jsfiddle.net/XGunn/). Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

What if you detect `onmouseover` on the whole page (through event bubbling), and when it enters a new element find if the original element that you last observed is a parent of the current target element, if it is not then you know it exited the original DOM node, even if `onmouseout` did not fire.

Comment: I don't think the browser will ever forget to fire the `onmouseout` event after `onmouseover` is triggered

Comment: @JanDvorak while I would like to think so, I've seen similar expectations shattered when altering the DOM is involved.  While that doesn't seem like the case here, it should be noted that such assumptions are not always valid (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732818/if-you-delete-a-dom-element-do-any-events-that-started-with-that-element-contin)

Comment: Interesting link. I shouldn't be surprised IE did something wrong ;-)