# use onmouseout to run when mouse is not over the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read this topic [What event to use instead of onmouseout to run when mouse is not over the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184258/what-event-to-use-instead-of-onmouseout-to-run-when-mouse-is-not-over-the-elemen)

The proposed method has not approached me .

How to determine that the cursor is moved to a other element? 
I search alternative

Comment: What do you mean by **moved to a certain element** but not **over the element**? As for me, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are really looking for, but to check an event, that occures when entering / leaving an element you should use `onmouseenter / leave` -events

As an alternative you could check something similiar by writing your own snippet, something like that: (just an example approach)

```
$(document).mousemove(function(evt){
// lets say you look for something like #header
   var myTarget = "header";
   var currentTarget = $(evt.target);
   if(myTarget != currentTarget.attr('id') ) {
    console.log('not on header')
   } else {
    console.log('on header')  
   }
})
```

**edit**
Maybe you can give an example, so we could help more quick?

best